# create trace files using rumen

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to create trace files with rumen.

How do I use rumen to create trace files from Job logs?

Which type of job logs can be used and how do I generate them and where can I find them?

Are these logs same as one produced when programs like sort are run?

Can anyone guide/tell me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for Rumen has been included in 0.22. Since, 0.22 has not yet been released, the documentation can be got from the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1918) attachments.